# In linux, how to clear the search character highlight when the search is done?

Tags: linux

Take the command `man tar` for example, type `/-C`, you will find the character `-C` highlighted, done. Then you quit and type `man tar` again, the `-C` is still highlighted. My question is how to clear the highlight? Thanks.

Comment: Not really a programming question. SO is for programming. General usage questions should go on Superuser or maybe Unix/Linux.

Comment: Wait, you quit and rerun `man` and it's **still** highlighted? That's weird. Mine doesn't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man actually doesn't do this. `man` uses a different `pager` for displaying its large texts. The default pager is less `less`, and if you type `man less` and search for "undo search highlighting" you'll find that the key for this is `ESC`-`u`. (and you can try it out immediately;).

hope it helps.

ps. you can tell `man` to use a different pager with the `-P` option.

Answer (score 2):

I always just search for something that isn't there. `/sdjfhweioufhw`. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

See lines in `vimrc` file (`/etc/vimrc`):

```
" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
     syntax on
     set hlsearch
endif
```

Comment `set hlsearch` to stop highlighting the last used search pattern.

Comment: Of course, this is for `vim` editor only :D